# Magento 2: Category Pages from Page 2 shows without products always

Tags: magento2, pagination, category-view

I'm trying to migrate a `Magento 1.9.3.6` to `Magento 2.3` and I found a strange problem. I've got some categories with thousands of products, I can see 64 products in my first page or 16, but if I go to page 2 `http://v2.dendago.eus/moda?p=2` it says that there is no product. In any category happens the same. I've re-indexed and cleaned cache multiple times.

Any advice?

Comment: @job zangitu have you verified the migrated products which are assigned to correct wbesites

Comment: If I select to show 64 products, I see 64. Then I change to 16 and go to page 2 and they are missing. It shouldn't be related to the website, is it?

Comment: Got it. I assume something code level issue. do u have any customizations related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the file `vendor\magento\module-elasticsearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\SearchResultApplier.php`

Find `apply()` method and replace it with the below function. 
Magento recently introduced hotfix by adding `$this->collection->setPageSize(null);` to the `SearchResultApplier.php` class.

```
public function apply()
    {
        if (empty($this->searchResult->getItems())) {
            $this->collection->getSelect()->where('NULL');
            return;
        }
        $ids = [];
        foreach ($this->searchResult->getItems() as $item) {
            $ids[] = (int)$item->getId();
        }
        $this->collection->setPageSize(null);
        $this->collection->getSelect()->where('e.entity_id IN (?)', $ids);
        $orderList = join(',', $ids);
        $this->collection->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER);
        $this->collection->getSelect()->order("FIELD(e.entity_id,$orderList)");
    }
```

Add a [plugin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) on above class.

Comment: You're goddam right!! Thanks!